# Internet stops working after a while

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I recently upgraded from 12 to ubuntu 14 and since then I am getting this issue. My problem is that after a while using the internet it stops working and to get it working again I have to disconnect and connect to the internet again. I am using ethernet on my PC. Any idea? I have tried tons of solutions but none of them are working..

Comment: did you unplug and plug your router?..... just kiddin - sounds like a contract is not being renewed as it should... have you checked your network settings? drivers? what do you mean by connecting and reconnecting - software / hardware? pc / router / network card?

Comment: @dsblind, by connecting and reconnecting I meant restarting the network manager. The driver is ok too I guess. I have not touched it after the upgrade and in case of network settings I have left the default. and hey plus 1 for  `did you unplug and plug your router?`

Comment: well before you go into complicated configurations, try working with defaults. your setup should be configured to automatically configure itself. so - just make sure that all is up to date. for example, check at your pc vendor's site - and compare with existing drivers. also - check router firmware version and make sure it's up to date. also - see router configuration - I'd bet that there's some feature turned on that shouldn't  be (for example - DMZ, beamforming etc - is preventing the lease from being renewed)

Comment: @dsblind, this issue is persisting ever since I have upgrade the ubuntu version to 14 , before that it was working fine.

Comment: Well is your hardware sufficient for 14? Did you try to reinstall Ubuntu? Maybe try and use WireShark - see if during the lost of connection your pc broadcasts a request for lease renewal